# WiFi + LAN network bridging issue

Tags: network, wifi

I'm trying to bridge a wifi network to some devices that are network connected directly to my MacPro but am running into problems.

Both networks work fine on their own but when bridged both go inactive, and I also lose WiFi controls i.e. what network to choose in my available area.

Is there something i'm doing wrong? I couldn't find any meaningful Apple documentation on the feature.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you share what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: What im trying to do is access a devices on network A via network B, using the Mac Pro as a bridge because it is a client on both networks. so that when I type 192.168.1.3 into a browser on my phone that is on network B i can access the control page for a device on network A

Network A consists of 5 devices with manually assigned IPs cabled into a small netgear switch with my Mac Pro. Network B is a WiFi only network consisting of a couple of APs run through a EdgeRouter X which is also assigning IPs to clients by DHCP. The Mac Pro is also a client on this network.

Comment: It would be helpful to include the details of your comment to your OQ ( Original Question ). Comments are here to help construct useful questions, not to stay forever.

Answer (score 0):

go to System Preferences > Sharing and check "Internet Sharing" and choose WiFi in the first drop down and Thunderbolt in the second.

Answer (score 0):

The IP address attribution choice should be the same on the 2 ends of your bridged interfaces, since they conctitute a uniq network starting when you bridge them.

You should chose manually or DHCP, and in the manual case, your IP addresses plan should be coherent:
same IP on both interfaces, differents IP addresses on every side of the networks for every equipment connected.
Once this is fully correct, you will have to activate the new interface `Wifi & TS3+>'.